# Custom logging with NLog on database

Tags: c#, database, nlog

I have some problem with NLog. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41971951/2872397) that said

> If you want custom layout properties (NLog calls them layout renderers) you can use the EventProperties Layout Renderer.

I wrote some config :

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
autoReload="true"
throwExceptions="false"
internalLogLevel="on" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

<targets>
  <!-- database target  -->
  <target name="databaseauthentication"
          xsi:type="Database"
          connectionString="Data Source = [....]; Initial Catalog = [....]; User Id = [....]; Password = [....]"
          commandText="exec dbo.InsertAuthentication
                        @company,
                        @firstname,
                        @lastname,
                        @ip,
                        @pcname,
                        @additionalInfo">
    <parameter name="@company" layout="${event-properties:item=companyValue}" />
    <parameter name="@firstname" layout="${event-properties:item=firstnameValue}" />
    <parameter name="@lastname" layout="${event-properties:item=lastnameValue}" />
    <parameter name="@ip" layout="${event-properties:item=ipValue}" />
    <parameter name="@pcname" layout="${event-properties:item=pcnameValue}" />
    <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${event-properties:item=additionalInfoValue}" />
  </target>
</targets>


<rules>
   <logger levels="Info" name="asyncdatabaseauthenticationLogger" writeTo="asyncdatabaseauthentication"/>
   <logger levels="Info" name="databaseauthenticationLogger" writeTo="databaseauthentication"/>
</rules>
</nlog>
```

And used that like :

```
 public static void SendLogin()
        {

            var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, databaseAuthenticateLogger.Name, "Message");
            eventInfo.Properties["firstnameValue"] = "My Fist Name;
            eventInfo.Properties["lastnameValue"] = "My Last Name";
            eventInfo.Properties["companyValue"] = "My Company";
            eventInfo.Properties["ipValue"] = "IP";
            eventInfo.Properties["pcnameValue"] = "PC Name";
            eventInfo.Properties["additionalInfoValue"] = "Login";
            databaseAuthenticateLogger.Log(eventInfo);
        }
```

But this code don't work. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is confusing and won't help others much. This has nothing to do with databases or custom properties. Please read how the `<rules>` work. See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#logger-name-filter

Answer (score 1):

The Above code is true, But We need to add this part in c# code :

```
static Logger databaseAuthenticateLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("databaseauthenticationLogger");
static Logger asyncdatabaseAuthenticateLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("asyncdatabaseauthenticationLogger");
```

Everythings works good.

Comment: You can also change it to `<logger levels="Info" name="*" writeTo="databaseauthentication"/>` (Then any logger will reach the database)